# does regular expression works when i translate them into another language?

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, ios4

For example: `@"^\s*([a-zA-Z]*)\s*$"`, this is a regular expression,

Now i translated this expression into Chinese: `@"^\小號*([一-ž一-ž]*)\小號*$"`

Will it work (always)?

Comment: mean that just by translating into another language , will it work ? or do we need to also manage it by adding some extra chars too ?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably you should use UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt it. Now I don't know Mandarin, Cantonese or any other "Chinese" language, so I can't tell what these "translations" actually mean. But I'm pretty sure you can't just go and transliterate the ASCII escape sequences into Chinese characters.

`\s` is a shorthand for whitespace. I'm betting `\小號` isn't.

`[A-Z]` means "any character between `A` and `Z`. So `[一-ž]` might work if the Unicode code point value of `一` is indeed below that of `ž`, and if those actually encompass the range of Chinese letters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not, as every language has its own syntax and keywords, same it is applied for RegEx also.

May some RegEx flavors have some extra or less features compared to another (for example, `PCRE flavor` and `.NET flavor`, and an pattern `(?<=\w+),`. `PCRE engine` would fail to match the pattern, but the `.NET engine` would do.). But, how the core keywords and syntax could change?

Moreover, `[a-z]` would match only English-like letters ranges from code-point 97(dec) to 122(dec), and it would include code-point 65(dec) to 90(dec), if matching `case-insensitive`. If you use `\p{L}` (LETTER class), it would match any letters from any language.